# How can I fix 'this.reduce() is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my code :

```js
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const reducer = (acc, guildCount) => acc + guildCount;
    const results = client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size');
    
    console.log(results)
    let guildCount  = results.reduce(reducer, 0)
    console.log(guildCount)

    renderTemplate(res, req, "index.ejs", { guildCount });
  });
```

Some details :`

`client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size')` return `Promise { <pending> }`.

The error when I want load that :
`TypeError: results.reduce is not a function`
``

This code work :

```js
client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size')
    .then(results => {
        console.log(`${results.reduce((acc, guildCount) => acc + guildCount, 0)} total guilds`);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

But I have to define the result in a variable in order to export it.

**How can I fix this? Is there another way to define the result with reduce?**

Comment: When the promise resolves what format is `results` in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce method works on arrays, so if **reduce** is **undefined** first thing you know 'results' is not Array. Now the question is why?

```
const results = client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size');
```

is an async method which is returning a promise. and when you use it without **.then()**

you will get a promise object in return, not the array. you will have to wait for the promise to get resolved.

```
const results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size');
```

to fix this  you can use **async await**

```
  app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const reducer = (acc, guildCount) => acc + guildCount;
    const results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size');
    
    console.log(results)
    let guildCount  = results.reduce(reducer, 0)
    console.log(guildCount)

    renderTemplate(res, req, "index.ejs", { guildCount });
  });
```

for more info about [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

and [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is the correct one. You're method has to be asynchronous from that point forward. Once async, always async. No way to force it back to synchronous.

Luckily, the `.get()` method you are in is already async, so just move everything after that into the `.then()`:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const reducer = (acc, guildCount) => acc + guildCount;
  client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size')
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
      let guildCount  = results.reduce(reducer, 0)
      console.log(guildCount);

      renderTemplate(res, req, "index.ejs", { guildCount });
    }).catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Your `catch()` should also respond to the request at least with a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` is Array helper, where `result` is `promise` ,

Thus either do your operations inside `then` like

```
client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size').then(results => results.reduce(reducer, 0))
```

OR

Use `async` `await`

```
const start = async () => {
 ...
 const results = await client.shard.fetchClientValues('guilds.cache.size')
 results.reduce(reducer, 0)
 ...
}
start()
```